# How can I debug python using Emacs in MS Windows?

Tags: python, emacs, windows-7, pdb

It seems I'm some kind of rare plant... I have to debug python scripts
in windows 7, 64bit. And since I use it for everything, especially as an IDE, I
would like to do it in emacs.

But I'm just not able to do so: M-x pdb gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pdb.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdb.pdb'; 'pdb' is not a package

Debugger exited abnormally with code 1
```

There is no pdb.exe available in my anaconda distribution, and I have
not been able to find such a program.

I installed winpdb and tried rpdb2 instead of pdb. It starts, but
there doesn't seem to be any emacs integration.

Since emacs, python and windows are involved, I thought this is the
correct forum, but I' not sure.

I'm using emacs 25.2, python 3.6.1 and am a python rookie.

Comment: Does this happen even before it asks you how to run pdb? If not, what do you enter in that prompt?

Comment: It happened after it asks how to run pdb. I just accepted the default, because I didn't know that pdb is not a separate program...

Comment: That's correct.. I see you answered your question too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to run pdb like this:

```
python -m pdb  "test_rtc.py"
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the [realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud/) package

Then add this to your init file:

```
(defun sdev/init-realgud
  (interactive)
  (load-library "realgud"))  
(sdev/init-realgud 1)
```